# CSS- dropdown menu transparent background when hovering but I want an opaque color from the beginning of animation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm newbie in CSS and I have set a dropdown menu. When hovering, the dropping menu has a transparent background. How make the background with  an opaque color from the beginning of animation ? I have tried several configurations but none works: so far my dropdown menu has a transparent background when dropping.

**Update : okay the hovering now is opaque since the beginning but there is still a lag with the fade-outing of the text. So far the text remain here behing the drop down menu then disappears brutally. Maybe someone have an hint to fix that ?**

**here my codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/93kz5pmzp4** you will see a little lag with transparent color then will come opacity.  I would have the opacity from the beggining.

```js
import React from 'react'
import style from "./Menu.module.css"; 

export default (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={style.menu}>
        <div> Current link </div>
        <div className={style.menu__container}>
          <button className={style.menu__button}>Dropdown</button>
          <div className={style.menu__content}>
            <Link /* className={style.link} */ to="/portfolio/">Portfolio {props.portfolio}</Link>
            <Link to="/blog/">Blog {props.blog}</Link>
            <Link to="/prestations/">Prestations {props.prestations}</Link>
            <Link to="/aboutus/">About us {props.aboutus}</Link>
            <Link to="/contact/">Contact {props.contact}</Link> 
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```css
 /* MENU */

    .menu{ 
      margin-left: 15%;
      margin-top: -0.5em;
      transition: width 2s;
    }


    /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
    .menu__container{
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

  /* Dropdown Button */
  .menu__container .menu__button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
  }

   /* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
   .menu__container:hover .menu__button {
    background-color: #3e8e41;}


  /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
  .menu__content {
   /*  display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1; */

    visibility: hidden; /* hides sub-menu */
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    /* make content 2em higher than container */
    transform: translateY(-2em);

    z-index: -1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
  }

    /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
    .menu__container:hover .menu__content {
      /* display: block; */
      visibility: visible; /* shows sub-menu */
      background-color: white; 
      opacity: 1;
      z-index: 1;
      transform: translateY(0%);
      transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s; }

  /* Links inside the dropdown */
  .menu__content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }

  /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
  .menu__content a:hover {background-color: white;}
```

Any hint would be great,
Thanks

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)? It will be easier for someone to help you that way.

Comment: your code will not generate transparent background, i think you missed something, transparent background will generate by opacity or rgba, please check these two properties

Comment: @Tholle : okay here my codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/93kz5pmzp4 .

Comment: @Charan I want create opaque background displaying from the beginning of dropping

Comment: @Webman Great. The background is orange for me. Do you mean that you want it to become orange straight away, and not transition from transparent to orange?

Comment: Yeah I have made it orange to make the demonstration more visible, yeah that it I would that the chosen color to be displayed opaquely from the very beginning of animation.

Comment: Also the text disappears brutally after the animation, I wonder why it not smoothly disappears with the growing of the menu-content's opacity - for further's question

Comment: you should change transition property from 'all' to specific property (transform) or whatever you want in transition
this css name :- (menu__content)

Comment: okay I have made the change but in my side there is alway the little lag in the transition, text's disappearing brutally, I can't figure out what is this phenomenon

Comment: I think its because of transition delay. Changing it to "transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;" might help.

Comment: Its because of the z-index:-1;  the drop down is under the text until the animation is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition of your Z-index is affecting it. You could imagine it like the div is slowly and little by little going in front of the text.

i think this codepen may help in explaining this.

https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/gboJf

```
<div class="wall wall-1"></div>
<div class="wall wall-2"></div>
<div class="wall wall-3"></div>
```